# How to rotate the watermark text to a certain angle using react-image-process

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-process to add watermark to my image and I'm using React to render this inside a component.

code:

```
render() {

    return (
      <ReactImageProcess
        mode="waterMark"
        waterMarkType="text"
        waterMark={'WATER'}
        fontBold={false}
        fontSize={20}
        fontColor="#396"
        coordinate={[10, 20]}
      >
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/youtube/http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv=aNwnPElsJGE"/>
      </ReactImageProcess>

    );
  }
```

this is the output:

[image]

However I want to rotate the watermark text to a certain angle. I'm not sure if this lib provides this ability, any ideas /suggestions on how to rotate the watermark text?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the selected library. The only supported rotation is of the image itself when you set the "mode" to "rotate". However, then you cannot apply the waterMark. There is no option to rotate just the watermark text.

See More: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-process